# how to use vim to automatically format xml tags when I press 'enter'? Should I write a plugin or modify vimrc?

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm working on an html file, and my cursor is between the open and close tags:

```
<button>I</button >
```

when I hit enter, I want vim to automatically format to this:

```
<button >
  I
</button >
```

`I` is the cursor position.

I'm thinking about modifying vimrc file, something like:

```
inoremap <CR>  "if previous character is > and next character is <, then <CR>O"
```

But I don't know how to get the previous/next character of the cursor.

I hope this makes sense,
I tried to search everywhere but I couldn't find any help, maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords, or taking the wrong approach.

Comment: In the editing toolbar you've a button for code formatting, don't bother inserting spaces after < signs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> '<CR>' . (search('\V>\%#<','bcn') ? '<Esc>O' : '')
```

Comment: inoremap <CR> "if previous character is > and next character is <, then <CR><Esc>O else <CR>". sorry, i can not speak english.

Comment: `:help search()`, `:help <expr>`, `:help /\%#`.